# Beginning Struts 2

Tags: maven, struts2

I am creating the first application with struts eclipse: looking at the blank template included in the struts download I saw that he puts the action helloworld under `web-inf/src/java/example` and `struts.xml` file is duplicated under `web-inf/src/java` and  java `resources/src`.

If I try to replicate it in a new dynamic web application it tells me that the action is not mapped. Instead, if I move the class under java resources `/src` it works.

Someone can help me to understand where I have to put stuff and why `struts.xml` is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different places. `web-inf/src/java` is in the `.war` file, but `resources/src` doesn't exist.

There's `struts.xml` in the `src/main/resources` in the project files. This is correct location, when the `.war` is created the file is copied inside it under `WEB-INF/classes`. This location will be use by web server to initialize Struts2 application.

The folder `web-inf/src` contains only copy of project source files, including files from `src/main/resources` which is a *source* folder. These files are optional, created by [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/).

Comment: What do you think about this?